# C++ code doesnt compile because multiple symbol error

Tags: c++

I tried to compile the below code:
Here is the server.h code (https://codeshare.io/an3XW4)

```
///////////////HEADER FILES///////////////
#include <pthread.h>
#include "Server.h"

///////////////FUNCTIONS///////////////
/*Thread Main Function
  Variable Definition:
  -- thread_arguments: arguments which thread should be used
  Return Value: NULL
*/
void *threadMain(void *thread_arguments){
    int     client_socket;      //socket descriptor for client

    //Guarantees that thread resources are deallocated upon return
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    //Pass the arguments
    client_socket = ((THREAD_ARGUMENTS*)thread_arguments)->client_socket;
    //Deallocate memory for argument
    free(thread_arguments);
    //Handle the client request
    handleClientRequest(client_socket);

    return (NULL);
}
```

THIS IS TIMEUTILITY.C, i dont understand much about C, im a programmer in java and more higher level languages of that sort.

```
///////////////HEADER FILES///////////////
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "Server.h"

///////////////FUNCTIONS///////////////
/*Set Timer Function
  Variable Definition:
  -- timer: itimerval structure
  -- type: timer type
  -- interval_sec: it_interval seconds
  -- interval_usec: it_interval microseconds
  -- value_sec: it_value seconds
  -- value_usec: it_value microseconds
  Return value: NULL
*/
void setTimer(  struct itimerval    timer,
                int                 type,
                u_int32             interval_sec,
                u_int32             interval_usec,
                u_int32             value_sec,
                u_int32             value_usec){
    //Set the time out value
    timer.it_interval.tv_sec = interval_sec;
    timer.it_interval.tv_usec = interval_usec;
    //Set the first time out value
    timer.it_value.tv_sec = value_sec;
    timer.it_value.tv_usec = value_usec;

    //Set the timer
    if (setitimer(type, &timer, NULL) != 0){
        dieWithSystemMessage("setitimer() failed");
    }

    return;
}
/*Get GMT Time Function (including System time and File time)
  Variable Definition:
  -- url: the request url except domain name and port number
  -- signal_value: signal that decide which kind of time needed
  Return value: tm struct in GMT Format
*/
struct tm *getTimeInGMTFormat(char *url, int signal_value){
    struct stat     file_information;   //file information sstructure
    time_t          t;                  //time structure

    //signal_value equals to 0, get the system current time
    if (!signal_value){
        time(&t);
    }
    //signal_value not equals to 0, get the file time(Create time, Modify time, Access time...)
    else if (stat(url, &file_information) != -1){
        switch(signal_value){
            //signal_value is 1, get the file create time
            case 1: t = file_information.st_atime;  break;
            //signal_value is 2, get the file modify time
            case 2: t = file_information.st_mtime;  break;
            //signal_value is others
            default:                                break;
        }
    }
    //Cannot find the file information
    else{
        dieWithUserMessage("stat() failed(cannot find the file information), file name", url);
    }

    return gmtime(&t);
}

/*Convert Time Format to a string
  Variable Definition:
  -- gmt_time: tm struct in GMT format
  -- signal_value: signal that decide which time format to convert
  Return value: time string in GMT format
*/
char *convertTimeFormat(struct tm *gmt_time, int signal_value){
    char    *gmt_time_string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (TIME_SIZE + 1));   //time in GMT format string

    //According to the signal_value, convert time to different format 
    switch(signal_value){
        case 1:
            strftime(gmt_time_string, TIME_SIZE, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", gmt_time);
            break;
        case 2:
            strftime(gmt_time_string, TIME_SIZE, "%A, %d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S GMT", gmt_time);
            break;
        case 3:
            gmt_time_string = asctime(gmt_time);
            gmt_time_string[strlen(gmt_time_string) - 1] = '\0';
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return gmt_time_string;
}

/*Compare the If-Modified-Since field and Last-Modified field Function
  Variable Definition:
  -- url: the request url except domain name and port number
  -- modified_time_string: If-Modified-Since field value
  Return Value: if If-Modified-Since field equals to Last-Modified field, return 1; else return 0
*/
bool compareModifiedTime(char *url, char *modified_time_string){
    struct tm   *file_modified_time = getTimeInGMTFormat(url, 2);   //tm struct with the file last modified time
    int         i;                                                  //counter

    //Test the modified time is equal(three format: RFC 1123, RFC 1036, and ANSI C's format)
    for (i = 1; i < NUMBER_SIZE; i++){
        if (strcmp(modified_time_string, convertTimeFormat(file_modified_time, i)) == 0){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But when I try to compile it, using g++ (C++ compiler) (the code was natively written in C), i get a weird error, anyone understand why? This is the full code of the Thread.C

```
/home/justin/Documents/dcn_streaming_video/server/Thread.c:23: multiple definition of `client_rtcp_port'
TimeUtility.o:/home/justin/Documents/dcn_streaming_video/server/TimeUtility.c:36: first defined here
Thread.o: In function `threadMain(void*)':
/home/justin/Documents/dcn_streaming_video/server/Thread.c:23: multiple definition of `client_rtp_port'
TimeUtility.o:/home/justin/Documents/dcn_streaming_video/server/TimeUtility.c:36: first defined here
Thread.o: In function `threadMain(void*)':
/home/justin/Documents/dcn_streaming_video/server/Thread.c:27: multiple definition of `range_end'
TimeUtility.o:/home/justin/Documents/dcn_streaming_video/server/TimeUtility.c:37: first defined here
Thread.o: In function `threadMain(void*)':
/home/justin/Documents/dcn_streaming_video/server/Thread.c:27: multiple definition of `range_start'
TimeUtility.o:/home/justin/Documents/dcn_streaming_video/server/TimeUtility.c:37: first defined here
Thread.o: In function `threadMain(void*)':
/home/justin/Documents/dcn_streaming_video/server/Thread.c:27: multiple definition of `status'
TimeUtility.o:/home/justin/Documents/dcn_streaming_video/server/TimeUtility.c:39: first defined here
Thread.o: In function `threadMain(void*)':
/home/justin/Documents/dcn_streaming_video/server/Thread.c:31: multiple definition of `session_id'
TimeUtility.o:/home/justin/Documents/dcn_streaming_video/server/TimeUtility.c:39: first defined here
Thread.o: In function `threadMain(void*)':
/home/justin/Documents/dcn_streaming_video/server/Thread.c:33: multiple definition of `rtp_address'
TimeUtility.o:/home/justin/Documents/dcn_streaming_video/server/TimeUtility.c:40: first defined here
Thread.o:(.bss+0x50): multiple definition of `protocol_method'
TimeUtility.o:/home/justin/Documents/dcn_streaming_video/server/TimeUtility.c:55: first defined here
Thread.o:(.bss+0x60): multiple definition of `protocol_type'
TimeUtility.o:/home/justin/Documents/dcn_streaming_video/server/TimeUtility.c:60: first defined here
```

Comment: Can you show the entire file?

Comment: Which file? the c code?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: My guess is that all those symbols are *defined* (instead of *declared*) in a header file that you include in multiple [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)), and with that you break the [one-definition rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule).

Comment: `TimeUtility.c`

Comment: When other people edit your question, take care not to revert those unless they are clearly wrong. Right now you have added back the code snippets as ***javascript***. Please [read the formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: @SamOrozco I have updated it. i didnt mean to edit , i had to add extra details to keep SO happy

Comment: And please read the comment by @NathanOliver, because we don't need to see *all* your actual code, just a short example that exhibits the problem you have. Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I added the rest of the code at Sam Orozco's request.....i never intended to add the rest of the code

Comment: Lastly, the problem is probably not in the source files, but in the *header file* (as per my first comment). So it would be better to let us see that one (`Server.h`)  instead.

Comment: What was the compilation command used? What is the content of `Server.h`?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/an3XW4       this is the server code

Comment: Yes the problem is what I thought. Take a closer look at the section "GLOBAL VARIABLES" in that header file. You *define* the variables. They should only be defined in a *single source file*, and then *declared* in the header file.

Comment: so should i remove them from the global variables section?

Comment: Ok I think I will take a different approach to solve my problem, I am thinking of just making a C++ program and including my c program in it.

Answer (score -1):

As others have indicated, I do not see the whole source code, specifically, the Server.h which probably does not use multiple inclusion guards (i.e top level ifdef or  pragma once).

Comment: Besides really being a comment, header include guards won't protect against multiple inclusions in different translation units.

Comment: Your global section defines and declares the variables Add extern to prevent the clash. I.e extern client_rtcp_port etc.